# Ubuntu + Tomcat7.0 +jdk7, hs_err_pid%.log file kept generating every hour

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

**UPDATE:I install a Oracle version of jdk1.7, and use update-alternative to use the Oracle jdk instead of openjdk, then the problem is gone. Some of my frds said that openJDK may have bug sometimes. Not sure why but anyway it is resolved know.**

Hello guys I am kind of new to linux, but recently i rent a web hosting server to test my own project.(os:ubuntu 12.04, and it is pre-installed with Tomcat7, mysql, nginx and jdk7)

The interesting thing happened after yesterday I deployed a webapp to the tomcat. The hs_err_pidxxxxx.log kept generating every one hour. Here is the screenshots of the related error logs generated:

```
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  3880 May 28 13:36 dev
drwxr-xr-x 101 root root  4096 May 28 13:35 etc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 May 25 13:25 home
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19561 May 27 23:06 hs_err_pid11601.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19561 May 28 00:06 hs_err_pid11670.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19512 May 28 01:06 hs_err_pid11866.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19514 May 28 02:06 hs_err_pid13256.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19517 May 28 03:06 hs_err_pid13485.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19563 May 28 04:06 hs_err_pid13524.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19567 May 28 05:06 hs_err_pid13567.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19665 May 28 06:06 hs_err_pid13606.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 18971 May 28 13:37 hs_err_pid1375.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19517 May 28 07:06 hs_err_pid13981.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19712 May 28 08:06 hs_err_pid14020.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19513 May 28 09:06 hs_err_pid14059.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19518 May 28 10:06 hs_err_pid14098.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 18981 May 28 11:06 hs_err_pid14289.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 19081 May 28 12:06 hs_err_pid14783.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 18984 May 28 13:06 hs_err_pid14945.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 18977 May 28 14:37 hs_err_pid2029.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 18974 May 28 16:37 hs_err_pid2386.log
-rw-r-----   1 root root 18974 May 28 17:37 hs_err_pid2428.log
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Aug 14  2012 initrd.img -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  4096 May 27 11:20 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jun 12  2014 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Aug  6  2012 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Aug  6  2012 media
```

So you saw all the files generated at the 6th min of every hour? I found this and tried to restart my machine once at May28 13:37, tomcat was restarted automatically together with the system, then the error files started to generated at every 37th min of a hour. At first I didn't realize the cause of this, until I shut down the tomcat server, then the error log gone!

These error logs are really annoying and the memory java consumed is also very high when Tomcat is on. Here is the result when I run the command `ps aux --sort rss`

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [bdi-default]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May28   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May28   0:00 [kblockd]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May28   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [khubd]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May28   0:00 [md]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [kworker/0:1]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   May28   0:00 [ksmd]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   May28   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May28   0:00 [crypto]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May28   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [kworker/u:2]
root        61  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May28   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root       195  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [jbd2/xvda1-8]
root       196  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May28   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       408  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   May28   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       416  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:04 [kworker/0:2]
root      2232  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    May28   0:00 [flush-202:0]
root       745  0.0  0.0  25524   168 ?        Ssl  May28   0:00 /usr/sbin/gshelld
daemon     701  0.0  0.0  16912   372 ?        Ss   May28   0:00 atd
root       526  0.0  0.0  15192   400 ?        S    May28   0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
root       266  0.0  0.0  17236   636 ?        S    May28   0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root       895  0.0  0.0   4404   736 ?        S    May28   0:00 /bin/sh /alidata/server/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/alidata/server/mysql/data --pid-file=/alidata/server/mysq
root       343  0.0  0.0  21504   864 ?        S    May28   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       344  0.0  0.0  21504   872 ?        S    May28   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
root       696  0.0  0.0  14508   976 tty2     Ss+  May28   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
root      1255  0.0  0.0  14508   976 tty1     Ss+  May28   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
root      1195  0.0  0.0  30944   980 ?        Ss   May28   0:00 nginx: master process /alidata/server/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /alidata/server/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
root       700  0.0  0.1  19116  1048 ?        Ss   May28   0:00 cron
102        652  0.0  0.1  23944  1076 ?        Ss   May28   0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
root      3191  0.0  0.1  16852  1204 pts/0    R+   00:44   0:00 ps aux --sort rss
nobody     765  0.0  0.1 527228  1296 ?        Ssl  May28   0:00 /usr/sbin/nscd
root       271  0.0  0.1  21648  1420 ?        Ss   May28   0:00 /sbin/udevd --daemon
syslog     619  0.0  0.1 249472  1448 ?        Sl   May28   0:01 rsyslogd -c5
root       790  0.0  0.1  23440  1452 ?        S    May28   0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
ntp       1328  0.0  0.2  33756  2112 ?        Ss   May28   0:02 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 104:108
root         1  0.0  0.2  24208  2180 ?        Ss   May28   0:00 /sbin/init
root       832  0.0  0.2 463408  2588 ?        Ssl  May28   0:21 /usr/local/aegis/aegis_update/AliYunDunUpdate
root       604  0.0  0.2  50036  2924 ?        Ss   May28   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      1451  0.0  0.3 186592  3268 ?        Sl   May28   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
root      1384  0.0  0.3 584308  3892 ?        Sl   May28   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon
root      2743  0.0  0.3  79888  3900 ?        Ss   May28   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0    
root      2760  0.0  0.4  22328  4904 pts/0    Ss   May28   0:00 -bash
root      1352  0.1  0.7 676660  8116 ?        Sl   May28   1:09 /usr/local/aegis/alihids/AliHids 
root      1336  0.1  1.0 675236 10308 ?        Sl   May28   1:17 /usr/local/aegis/aegis_client/aegis_00_73/AliYunDun
www       1198  0.0  2.8  58080 28800 ?        S    May28   0:00 nginx: worker process                                                    
mysql     1171  0.0  4.1 536480 42704 ?        Sl   May28   0:14 /alidata/server/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/alidata/server/mysql --datadir=/alidata/server/mysql/data --plugin-dir
root      3035  0.3  7.4 997652 76192 pts/0    Sl   00:05   0:08 /alidata/server/java/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/alidata/server/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties
```

I also removed my deployed webapp from tomcat, but still the error log came...
Really need some help or hint on what should I do with this error file, I read some reference docs but didn't get too much idea.

---

Here is the hs_err_pidxxxxx.log, all very similar to this

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# pthread_getattr_np
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux_x86.cpp:718), pid=2428, tid=139723618129664
#
# JRE version:  (7.0_79-b14) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.5
# Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f13ec072000):  JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_new, id=2432, stack(0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000)]

Stack: [0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000],  sp=0x00007f13f0a007c0,  free space=136448845825k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x9263d3]
V  [libjvm.so+0x488c30]
V  [libjvm.so+0x7b231a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x7b23ad]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8d9514]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8e17ea]
V  [libjvm.so+0x7a7e42]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x00007f13ec072000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_new, id=2432, stack(0x0000000000000000,0x0000000000000000)]
  0x00007f13ec070000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2431, stack(0x00007f13f0a02000,0x00007f13f0b03000)]
  0x00007f13ec00a000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=2429, stack(0x00007f13f44cf000,0x00007f13f45d0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007f13ec06b800 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f13f0b03000,0x00007f13f0c04000] [id=2430]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4800K, used 85K [0x00000000d6800000, 0x00000000d6d30000, 0x00000000e0e00000)
  eden space 4288K,   2% used [0x00000000d6800000, 0x00000000d6815760, 0x00000000d6c30000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000d6c30000, 0x00000000d6c30000, 0x00000000d6cb0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x00000000d6cb0000, 0x00000000d6cb0000, 0x00000000d6d30000)
 tenured generation   total 10624K, used 0K [0x00000000e0e00000, 0x00000000e1860000, 0x00000000f5a00000)
   the space 10624K,   0% used [0x00000000e0e00000, 0x00000000e0e00000, 0x00000000e0e00200, 0x00000000e1860000)
 compacting perm gen  total 21248K, used 1022K [0x00000000f5a00000, 0x00000000f6ec0000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 21248K,   4% used [0x00000000f5a00000, 0x00000000f5aff948, 0x00000000f5affa00, 0x00000000f6ec0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Card table byte_map: [0x00007f13f0ff2000,0x00007f13f113f000] byte_map_base: 0x00007f13f093e000

Polling page: 0x00007f13f45dd000

Code Cache  [0x00007f13e9000000, 0x00007f13e9270000, 0x00007f13ec000000)
 total_blobs=75 nmethods=0 adapters=53 free_code_cache=48818Kb largest_free_block=49990080

Compilation events (0 events):
No events

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.034 loading class 0x00007f13f0ea82c0
Event: 0.034 loading class 0x00007f13f0ea8520
Event: 0.034 loading class 0x00007f13f0ea8520 done
Event: 0.034 loading class 0x00007f13f0ea82c0 done
Event: 0.034 loading class 0x00007f13f0ea5870 done
Event: 0.035 loading class 0x00007f13f0ea58a0
Event: 0.035 loading class 0x00007f13f0ea58a0 done
Event: 0.035 loading class 0x00007f13f0ea58d0
Event: 0.035 loading class 0x00007f13f0ea58d0 done
Event: 0.035 loading class 0x00007f13f0e8a670


Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 138141                             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 ca:01 138141                             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 138141                             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
01ee0000-01f01000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
d6800000-d6d30000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
d6d30000-e0e00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e0e00000-e1860000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
e1860000-f5a00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f5a00000-f6ec0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6ec0000-100000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13e0000000-7f13e0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13e0021000-7f13e4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13e4000000-7f13e4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13e4021000-7f13e8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13e9000000-7f13e9270000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13e9270000-7f13ec083000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13ec083000-7f13f0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0901000-7f13f0a02000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0a02000-7f13f0a05000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0a05000-7f13f0b03000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0b03000-7f13f0b04000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0b04000-7f13f0c4d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0c4d000-7f13f0dfe000 r--s 01d27000 ca:01 138110                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar
7f13f0dfe000-7f13f0f02000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0f02000-7f13f0f4b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0f4b000-7f13f0f51000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0f51000-7f13f0ff2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0ff2000-7f13f0ff5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f0ff5000-7f13f1045000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f1045000-7f13f104b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f104b000-7f13f10eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f10eb000-7f13f10f6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f10f6000-7f13f113e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f113e000-7f13f113f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f113f000-7f13f1147000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 138039                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f13f1147000-7f13f1346000 ---p 00008000 ca:01 138039                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f13f1346000-7f13f1347000 r--p 00007000 ca:01 138039                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f13f1347000-7f13f1348000 rw-p 00008000 ca:01 138039                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f13f1348000-7f13f1354000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048852                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7f13f1354000-7f13f1553000 ---p 0000c000 ca:01 1048852                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7f13f1553000-7f13f1554000 r--p 0000b000 ca:01 1048852                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7f13f1554000-7f13f1555000 rw-p 0000c000 ca:01 1048852                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
7f13f1555000-7f13f155f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048857                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
7f13f155f000-7f13f175f000 ---p 0000a000 ca:01 1048857                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
7f13f175f000-7f13f1760000 r--p 0000a000 ca:01 1048857                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
7f13f1760000-7f13f1761000 rw-p 0000b000 ca:01 1048857                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
7f13f1761000-7f13f1778000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048919                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
7f13f1778000-7f13f1977000 ---p 00017000 ca:01 1048919                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
7f13f1977000-7f13f1978000 r--p 00016000 ca:01 1048919                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
7f13f1978000-7f13f1979000 rw-p 00017000 ca:01 1048919                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
7f13f1979000-7f13f197b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f197b000-7f13f1983000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048850                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
7f13f1983000-7f13f1b82000 ---p 00008000 ca:01 1048850                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
7f13f1b82000-7f13f1b83000 r--p 00007000 ca:01 1048850                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
7f13f1b83000-7f13f1b84000 rw-p 00008000 ca:01 1048850                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
7f13f1b84000-7f13f1bad000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 138046                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f13f1bad000-7f13f1dac000 ---p 00029000 ca:01 138046                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f13f1dac000-7f13f1dad000 r--p 00028000 ca:01 138046                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f13f1dad000-7f13f1daf000 rw-p 00029000 ca:01 138046                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f13f1daf000-7f13f1dbd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 138061                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f13f1dbd000-7f13f1fbc000 ---p 0000e000 ca:01 138061                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f13f1fbc000-7f13f1fbe000 r--p 0000d000 ca:01 138061                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f13f1fbe000-7f13f1fbf000 rw-p 0000f000 ca:01 138061                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f13f1fbf000-7f13f1fc6000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048856                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7f13f1fc6000-7f13f21c5000 ---p 00007000 ca:01 1048856                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7f13f21c5000-7f13f21c6000 r--p 00006000 ca:01 1048856                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7f13f21c6000-7f13f21c7000 rw-p 00007000 ca:01 1048856                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
7f13f21c7000-7f13f21dc000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048621                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f13f21dc000-7f13f23db000 ---p 00015000 ca:01 1048621                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f13f23db000-7f13f23dc000 r--p 00014000 ca:01 1048621                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f13f23dc000-7f13f23dd000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 1048621                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f13f23dd000-7f13f24d8000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048860                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f13f24d8000-7f13f26d7000 ---p 000fb000 ca:01 1048860                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f13f26d7000-7f13f26d8000 r--p 000fa000 ca:01 1048860                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f13f26d8000-7f13f26d9000 rw-p 000fb000 ca:01 1048860                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
7f13f26d9000-7f13f27bb000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1184732                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f13f27bb000-7f13f29ba000 ---p 000e2000 ca:01 1184732                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f13f29ba000-7f13f29c2000 r--p 000e1000 ca:01 1184732                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f13f29c2000-7f13f29c4000 rw-p 000e9000 ca:01 1184732                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
7f13f29c4000-7f13f29d9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f29d9000-7f13f34c8000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 138068                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f13f34c8000-7f13f36c7000 ---p 00aef000 ca:01 138068                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f13f36c7000-7f13f3768000 r--p 00aee000 ca:01 138068                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f13f3768000-7f13f378b000 rw-p 00b8f000 ca:01 138068                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f13f378b000-7f13f37b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f37b8000-7f13f37ce000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048805                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7f13f37ce000-7f13f39cd000 ---p 00016000 ca:01 1048805                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7f13f39cd000-7f13f39ce000 r--p 00015000 ca:01 1048805                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7f13f39ce000-7f13f39cf000 rw-p 00016000 ca:01 1048805                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
7f13f39cf000-7f13f39e7000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048858                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f13f39e7000-7f13f3be6000 ---p 00018000 ca:01 1048858                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f13f3be6000-7f13f3be7000 r--p 00017000 ca:01 1048858                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f13f3be7000-7f13f3be8000 rw-p 00018000 ca:01 1048858                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
7f13f3be8000-7f13f3bec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f3bec000-7f13f3bee000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048866                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
7f13f3bee000-7f13f3dee000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 1048866                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
7f13f3dee000-7f13f3def000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 1048866                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
7f13f3def000-7f13f3df0000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 1048866                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
7f13f3df0000-7f13f3fa5000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048847                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f13f3fa5000-7f13f41a5000 ---p 001b5000 ca:01 1048847                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f13f41a5000-7f13f41a9000 r--p 001b5000 ca:01 1048847                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f13f41a9000-7f13f41ab000 rw-p 001b9000 ca:01 1048847                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
7f13f41ab000-7f13f41b0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f41b0000-7f13f41bd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 138044                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f13f41bd000-7f13f43bc000 ---p 0000d000 ca:01 138044                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f13f43bc000-7f13f43bd000 r--p 0000c000 ca:01 138044                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f13f43bd000-7f13f43be000 rw-p 0000d000 ca:01 138044                     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f13f43be000-7f13f43e0000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 1048861                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f13f4407000-7f13f4411000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f4411000-7f13f44c7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f44c7000-7f13f44cf000 rw-s 00000000 ca:01 1048991                    /tmp/hsperfdata_root/2428
7f13f44cf000-7f13f44d2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f44d2000-7f13f45d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f45dc000-7f13f45dd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f45dd000-7f13f45de000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f45de000-7f13f45e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f13f45e0000-7f13f45e1000 r--p 00022000 ca:01 1048861                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7f13f45e1000-7f13f45e3000 rw-p 00023000 ca:01 1048861                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
7fff3c9d3000-7fff3c9f4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff3c9ff000-7fff3ca00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
java_command: org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x926e30], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x926e30], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x7a5d40], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x7a5d40], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x7a5d40], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x7a5d40], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x7a5f80], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTRAP: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)
uname:Linux 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.15 NPTL 2.15 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 7815, NOFILE 1024, AS 1048576k
load average:0.00 0.01 0.05

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        1017972 kB
MemFree:          478304 kB
Buffers:           72536 kB
Cached:           237944 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           291448 kB
Inactive:         174416 kB
Active(anon):     155464 kB
Inactive(anon):      248 kB
Active(file):     135984 kB
Inactive(file):   174168 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                76 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        155448 kB
Mapped:            43112 kB
Shmem:               280 kB
Slab:              50744 kB
SReclaimable:      40756 kB
SUnreclaim:         9988 kB
KernelStack:        1720 kB
PageTables:         3240 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      508984 kB
Committed_AS:     789008 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:        8596 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359727484 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       36864 kB
DirectMap2M:     1011712 kB


CPU:total 1 (32 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, aes, ht, tsc

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x70d
cpu MHz     : 2300.070
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc up rep_good nopl pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips    : 4600.14
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 1017972k(478304k free), swap 0k(0k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_79-b14), built on Apr 16 2015 10:33:54 by "buildd" with gcc 4.6.3

time: Thu May 28 17:37:37 2015
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this crash is that JVM could not get required memory from the OS. For Example, if your machine itself has 8 GB RAM and if you configure -Xmx as 12GB, then JVM will try to request this memory when you create new objects.

In that time, if the JVM could not get enough memory, it will crash like this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Tomcat is actually using the Java 7 JVM  that is 64-bit? The JVM crash dump (that's what `hs_err_*` files are called) says: `There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.` and `In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit`. The crash dump is generated when the JVM (the native code) or a linked library performs an illegal action. While tomcat is running, ensure that you can monitor the JVM with `jps` command. If the JVM is running in 32-bit mode then it has access to only about 3.5GB memory on the heap (even when you have lots of virtual memory available -- this is where you could/should utilize 64-bit JVM).

The crash dump looks a little strange. The dump mostly implies an internal JVM/library bug. But I am confused that something like what you are doing is causing this. In my experience, it used to show the **problematic frame** that experienced the operating system violation. In your dumps, see if there is a problematic frame mentioned.

Another thing to try is to actually dump the Java threads when JVM sees OOMError. This is typically done by adding to `JAVA_OPTS` in `/etc/default/tomcat7` a new option: `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` so that you will come to know what the Java/native threads are actually doing when JVM runs into `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Thank you Kedar for giving the suggestions and the detailed analysis. As you said this more like a jvm bug, I actually install a Oracle version of jdk1.7, and use update-alternative to use the Oracle jdk instead of openjdk, then the problem is gone. Some of my frds said that openJDK may have bug sometimes. Not sure why but anyway it is resolved know....